# Pausing GPIO.output without affecting the rest of the code

Tags: python, gpio

I'm working on a real time face recognition program from an IP camera video stream that triggers a GPIO signal when a face is recognized.  After a face is first recognized, I need the GPIO not to be activated for a certain amount of time (e.g. 45 seconds).

I tried to insert `time.sleep(45)` after the GPIO signal is triggered, which seems to work **BUT** after 45 seconds of pausing, the video stream being analyzed is not live anymore. It starts with the very frame that came after the one where the face was recognized, in other words with a 45 seconds delay.

How could I get to pausing the GPIO output for 45 seconds and getting back to a live video stream being analyzed after that?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
relay = 23
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(relay, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(relay, 1)

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml')
cascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

#initiate id counter
id = 0

# names related to ids: example ==> Jenifer: id=1,  etc
names = ['None', 'Jenifer', 'Jenifer', 'Luciola'] 

# Initialize and start realtime video capture
cam = cv2.VideoCapture('ipcamera')
frame_rate = 1
prev = 0

# Define min window size to be recognized as a face
minW = 0.1*cam.get(3)
minH = 0.1*cam.get(4)

while True:
    
    time_elapsed = time.time() - prev
    res, image = cam.read()

    if time_elapsed > 1./frame_rate:
        prev = time.time()

    ret, img =cam.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale( 
        gray,
        scaleFactor = 1.2,
        minNeighbors = 5,
        minSize = (int(minW), int(minH)),
       )

    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:

        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)

        id, confidence = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])

        # Check if confidence is less than 100 ==> "0" is perfect match 
        if (confidence < 85):
            id = names[id]
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))
            GPIO.output(relay, 0)
            print("Ouverture du portail")
            time.sleep(1)
            GPIO.output(relay, 1)
        else:
            GPIO.output(relay, 1)
        
        cv2.putText(img, str(id), (x+5,y-5), font, 1, (255,255,255), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str(confidence), (x+5,y+h-5), font, 1, (255,255,0), 1)  
    
    cv2.imshow('camera',img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff # Press 'ESC' for exiting video
    if k == 27:
        break

# Do a bit of cleanup
print("\n [INFO] Exiting Program and cleanup stuff")
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Possum's solution works well.
Line 66:

```
            GPIO.output(relay, 1)
            cam.release()
            time.sleep(45)
            cam = cv2.VideoCapture('ipcamera')
            
        else:
```

Comment: Where did you put your sleep?  Did you try calling the `cam.release()` and then reinitialize it immediately after that?

Comment: I put my sleep after line 66 GPIO.output(relay, 1).

I did not try the solution you brought, and it seems to work well!

...
GPIO.output(relay, 1)
cam.release()
time.sleep(45)
cam = cv2.VideoCapture('ipcamera')
else:
...

Thank you for your help possum!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `threading.Thread` to create a thread that will run the camera stream in the background, so it will be unaffected by the `sleep` function. You could do something like this:

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2

gray = None
minW = None
minH = None

def camera_stream():
    def get_frames():
        while True:
            global minW
            global minH
            cv2.VideoCapture('ipcamera')
            minW = 0.1*cam.get(3)
            minH = 0.1*cam.get(4)
            res, image = cam.read()
            gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            yield gray_frame
    while True:
        global gray
        gray = next(get_frames)
        

thread = Thread(target=camera_stream, daemon=True)
thread.start()

...
```

Now wherever you used the variable `gray`, it should use the next frame in the camera stream that is constantly running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to simply define a function to check if the delay has passed.

I amended your code, haven't tested it, but i think it should work.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import cv2

relay = 23
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(relay, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(relay, 1)

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml')
cascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);
delay = 45
last_trigger = a = int(time.time()) - delay

def check_delay():
    globals(last_trigger, delay)
    current_time = int(time.time())
    current_delay = current_time - last_trigger
    if(current_delay < delay):
        return False
    else:
        return True

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

# initiate id counter
id = 0

# names related to ids: example ==> Jenifer: id=1,  etc
names = ['None', 'Jenifer', 'Jenifer', 'Luciola']

# Initialize and start realtime video capture
cam = cv2.VideoCapture('ipcamera')
frame_rate = 1
prev = 0

# Define min window size to be recognized as a face
minW = 0.1 * cam.get(3)
minH = 0.1 * cam.get(4)

while True:

    time_elapsed = time.time() - prev
    res, image = cam.read()

    if time_elapsed > 1. / frame_rate:
        prev = time.time()

    ret, img = cam.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.2,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(int(minW), int(minH)),
    )

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:

        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        id, confidence = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])

        # Check if confidence is less than 100 ==> "0" is perfect match
        if (confidence < 85):
            id = names[id]
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))
            GPIO.output(relay, 0)
            print("Ouverture du portail")
            time.sleep(1)
            if check_delay():
                GPIO.output(relay, 1)
                last_trigger = int(time.time())

        else:
            if check_delay():
                GPIO.output(relay, 1)
                last_trigger = int(time.time())

        cv2.putText(img, str(id), (x + 5, y - 5), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str(confidence), (x + 5, y + h - 5), font, 1, (255, 255, 0), 1)

    cv2.imshow('camera', img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff  # Press 'ESC' for exiting video
    if k == 27:
        break

# Do a bit of cleanup
print("\n [INFO] Exiting Program and cleanup stuff")
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: i just noticed a slight typo... at line 18, last_trigger = a = int(time.time()) - delay should be last_trigger = int(time.time()) - delay

Comment: Surprinsingly, it freezes when a face is recognized...